# Create .exe from .jar file using build.xml

Tags: xml, jar, exe

Is it possible to create an exe from the jar file using some script (build.xml). Currently I use a build file to create a jar and then create exe with Launch4J. Now I would like to make an exe of the application via a script. I would like to know if it is possible.

Comment: Windows or linux ?Did you tried Shell script ?

Comment: Of Course exe is for Windows and hence WIndows. I dint try shell script and I am not familiar with shell scripts

Comment: i tght tis way and asked for Linux :) You can't make the jar file executable on Linux.but shell script executable and have it call the java command to launch the app in the jar

Comment: am sorry @Peru This is not what i need.

Comment: @rIHaNJiTHiN Sorry to say this is not I needed. Its clear from the question that I already have an executable jar created using a build file as given in your link. Now I would like to create an EXE from the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enhance your research skills. It took me 2 seconds to find the part of the Launch4j documentation, where the special `launch4j` Ant task is explained. Look here: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Ant_task

So yes, it is possible. You can use Ant with that special task and it is documented.